# Creating a Virtualenv using Python

Tags: python, python-venv, python-3.10

--EDIT-- Using Ubuntu 22.04

I have recently installed Python 3.10, and I have different folders. Is this normal or did I mess up the installation?

```
virtualenv venv

created virtual environment CPython3.10.4.final.0-64 in 74ms
  creator CPython3Posix(dest=/home/aravinth/Bureau/aa/venv, clear=False, no_vcs_ignore=False, global=False)
  seeder FromAppData(download=False, pip=bundle, setuptools=bundle, wheel=bundle, via=copy, app_data_dir=/home/aravinth/.local/share/virtualenv)
    added seed packages: pip==22.1.2, setuptools==62.3.4, wheel==0.37.1
  activators BashActivator,CShellActivator,FishActivator,NushellActivator,PowerShellActivator,PythonActivator
```

```
ls venv
lib  local  pyvenv.cfg
```

I get this new local directory, now to activate the `Venv` I need to type:

```
source venv/local/bin/activate
```

Instead of typing:

```
source venv/bin/activate
```

Comment: You are using virtualenv instead of venv  so yah its normal...

Comment: Just tried installing Python 3.10.5 from source on Ubuntu 22.04, and then using `python3 -m pip install --user virtualenv` and `python3 -m virtualenv venv`, I got `bin lib pyvenv.cfg`, without the local folder.

Answer (score 1):

from:  https://python.land/virtual-environments/virtualenv

> **Python 3.4 and above** If you are running Python 3.4+, you can use the venv module baked into Python: `$ python -m venv [directory]` This
> command creates a venv in the specified directory and copies pip into
> it as well. If you’re unsure what to call the directory: venv is a
> commonly seen option; it doesn’t leave anyone guessing what it is. A
> little further in this article, we’ll take a close look at the
> directory that was just created. But let’s first look at how to
> activate this virtual environment.

[What’s inside a venv?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uwFRi.png)

Comment: Yes that is what I have been using now thanks